# "C’est attaquer le sceptre au nom du trône et la mitre au nom de l’autel"

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Que veut dire la phrase écrite en caractère gras:

> Être ultra, c’est aller au delà. **C’est attaquer le sceptre au nom du trône et la mitre au nom de l’autel** ; c’est malmener la chose qu’on traîne ; c’est ruer dans l’attelage ; c’est chicaner le bûcher sur le degré de cuisson des hérétiques ; c’est reprocher à l’idole son peu d’idolâtrie ; c’est insulter par excès de respect ; c’est trouver dans le pape pas assez de papisme, dans le roi pas assez de royauté, et trop de lumière à la nuit ; c’est être mécontent de l’albâtre, de la neige, du cygne et du lys au nom de la blancheur ; c’est être partisan des choses au point d’en devenir l’ennemi ; c’est être si fort pour, qu’on est contre.

Source: [Les misérables tome 3 Livre 3](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/03)

Comment: Plutôt que de vous donner la réponse... je prefère laisser Chateaubriand vous  donner un coup de main. Vous-aide-t-il s'il vous dit la même chose avec son : *"C'est être plus royaliste que le roi."* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comme tous les autres exemples cités, ces deux représentent le cas d'une personne qui cible la chose-même qu'il croit défendre, en raison de l'extrémité de son ardeur.

Le sceptre et le trône représentent le pouvoir et le droit du roi, donc la monarchie même (le roi porte le sceptre et s'assied sur le trône).

La mitre et l'autel représentent les offices du prêtre, donc l'église même (le prêtre porte la mitre et exécute ses fonctions sur l'autel).

À l'époque où se déroulent ces événements, comme tu le sais sans doute, on attaquait les anciennes institutions et même ceux qui semblaient vouloir les protéger faisaient parfois demi-tour ou se révélaient plus idéalistes que ces institutions mêmes, d'où la tendance à détruire ce qu'ils prétendaient aimer.

Comment: Hmmm... sceptre / trône mître / autel... je trouve quand même une certaine hiérarchie dans les **symboles** voire carrément-presque... une relation d'**accessoire** à Idée.

Answer (score 0):

Le fou du roi ou le bouffon si l'on préfère. C'était une fonction unique et plutôt intéressante de trouver ce qu'il se tramait sous la soutane ou derrière le trône. Est-ce que dans leur contrats de travail la clause liée aux risques de métier fut incluse ? Même tacite vu que les contrats de travail datent d'il y a peu...  Et si oui, gagnaient-ils bien leur vie en risquant leur têtes chaque fois quand ils ouvraient leur bouche ? et en même temps cela leur était demandé. Leur secrets ? La communication stratégique : poser des bonnes questions, savoir se taire, respirer...